# Ansible - How to loop with a dict and a module's values

Tags: networking, ansible

I'm trying to create a task with Ansible (=> 2.5) that will configure network interfaces such as that:

```
- name: Set up network interfaces addr
  interfaces_file:
    dest: "/etc/network/interfaces.d/{{ item.device }}"
    iface: "{{ item.device }}"
    state: present
    option: address
    value: "{{ item.addr }}"
  with_items:
   - "{{ network }}"
  when: item.addr is defined
  notify: Restart interface

- name: Set up network interfaces netmask
  interfaces_file:
    dest: "/etc/network/interfaces.d/{{ item.device }}"
    iface: "{{ item.device }}"
    state: present
    option: netmask
    value: "{{ item.netmask }}"
  with_items:
   - "{{ network }}"
  when: item.netmask is defined
  notify: Restart interface

- name: Set up network interfaces dns
  interfaces_file:
    dest: "/etc/network/interfaces.d/{{ item.device }}"
    iface: "{{ item.device }}"
    state: present
    option: dns-nameservers
    value: "{{ item.dns }}"
  with_items:
   - "{{ network }}"
  when: item.dns is defined
  notify: Restart interface

- name: Set up network interfaces dns-search
  interfaces_file:
    dest: "/etc/network/interfaces.d/{{ item.device }}"
    iface: "{{ item.device }}"
    state: present
    option: dns-search
    value: "{{ item.dns_search }}"
  with_items:
   - "{{ network }}"
  when: item.dns_search is defined
  notify: Restart interface
```

This works.
But from my point of view, that's not so clean ..
So I'm trying to use 2 loops ... Which is not working obviously.

```
- name: Set up network interfaces
  interfaces_file:
    dest: "/etc/network/interfaces.d/{{ item.iDunnoWhatToPutHere }}"
    iface: "{{ item.iDunnoWhatToPutHere }}"
    state: present
    option: {{ item.option }}
    value: "{{ item.value }}"
with_together:
  - "{{ network }}"
  - { option: address, value: item.0.addr }
  - { option: netmask, value: item.0.netmask }
  - { option: dns-nameservers, value: item.0.dns }
  when: item.dns_search is defined
  notify: Restart interface
  [...]
```

Edit: This is good but it's strict. I should loop on vars which should loop on each option and its value for any options. Because I also have options for bridge such as "vlan_raw_device, bridge_ports, bridge_stp ...". So it should just loop blindly on a dict of options and values.

Edit2: With variable network

```
network:
  - name: admin
    device: admin
    method: static
    address: X.X.X.X/X
    netmask: X.X.X.X
    up:
      net: X.X.X.X/X
      gateway: X.X.X.X/X
    down:
      net: X.X.X.X/X
      gateway: X.X.X.X/X
```

Why I'm trying all this ?

1. Because I need to change all the values if it has to be changed.
2. Because I want to restart (ifup, ifdown) only the interface that
3. Because I'm surprised that I have to use multiple times the same module.

Can you guys help me find out how to use that ?
Maybe it's not possible ?

Thanks folks !

Comment: in the original playbook with the 3 tasks, can you provide how the `network` variable looks like?

Comment: For sure, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

here is a task that will hopefully meet your needs. i have replaced the `interfaces_file` with `debug` module, just to print the variables you need to actually use in the `interfaces_file` module. for the sake of the demo, i added a second interface in the `network` variable:

playbook with the variable and the task:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    network:
    - name: admin
      device: admin
      method: static
      address: 10.10.10.22
      netmask: 255.255.255.0
      up:
        net: X.X.X.X/X
        gateway: X.X.X.X/X
      down:
        net: X.X.X.X/X
        gateway: X.X.X.X/X
    - name: admin22
      device: admin22
      method: static
      address: 20.20.20.22
      netmask: 255.255.255.192
      up:
        net: X.X.X.X/X
        gateway: X.X.X.X/X
      down:
        net: X.X.X.X/X
        gateway: X.X.X.X/X

  tasks:
  - name: process network config
    debug:
      msg: "dest: {{ item[0].name }}, option: {{ item[1].option }}, value: {{ item[0][item[1].value] }}"
    with_nested:
      - "{{ network }}"
      - [{ option: address, value: address }, { option: netmask, value: netmask }]
```

result:

```
TASK [process network config] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "dest: admin, option: address, value: 10.10.10.22"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "dest: admin, option: netmask, value: 255.255.255.0"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "dest: admin22, option: address, value: 20.20.20.22"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "dest: admin22, option: netmask, value: 255.255.255.192"
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! How would you do without the second line of with_nested ? 
Which means that all your options and values are stored in the variable network ?

Comment: why would i remove the 2nd line? i dont see it possible to achieve all these in a single task without passing the information that you want to modify more than 1 attributes.

Comment: My goal is to put all the informations in the host_vars and the single task should loop on all options and its values. The options are unpredictable, so for a host I could set the bridge and for another host, I could set the addr only. I'm just trying to do a generic task. Maybe it's impossible :(

Comment: then make a list variable with the structure of the 2nd line of `with_nested`, put it in the host_vars, and replace the 2nd line of the `with_nested` to that variable. the "framework" is there.